# Can you recommend a resource that lists the most common types of user input screen designs?

Tags: .net, asp.net, user-interface, user-input

Do you know a resource(kind of UI Design pattern catalog) that lists the most common types of user input screen designs and their pros and cons by suggesting in what cases that particular design would be beneficial?

I am looking for this in order to keep them in mind for web application usage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use http://ui-patterns.com/patterns for a great reference for various UI patterns for getting input from the user.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe some of these Smashing Magazine articles could help you:

http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/06/23/10-ui-design-patterns-you-should-be-paying-attention-to/

http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/02/25/designing-user-interfaces-for-business-web-applications/

Answer (score 1):

There's also the Yahoo! Design Pattern Library - http://developer.yahoo.com/ypatterns/

Answer (score 0):

And another possibly usefull link

http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/06/15/40-helpful-resources-on-user-interface-design-patterns/

Answer (score 0):

[Quince](http://quince.infragistics.com/) is an online UX and UI pattern library that you may find useful.

Ironically it has some useful information but an awful UI.